# How to programmatically change user assigned to a task?

Tags: api, tfs, command-line-interface

In TFS how could I use the API or command line to change the user assigned to a task?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Work Items - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) Rest API to update any work item field.

Example with PowerShell:

```
  $collectionUrl = "http://{tfs-url}:8080/tfs/{collection}"
  $workItemId = "1"
  $byPass = "true"
  $url = "$collectionUrl/_apis/wit/workitems/$workItemId?bypassRules=$($byPass)&api-version=3.0"

  #the "op : add" is also repleace existing value
  $body = '[
           {             
             "op":"add",
             "path":"/fields/System.AssignedTo",
             "value":"User Name"              
           }
           ]'

  try
  {
     Invoke-RestMethod -Method Patch -UseDefaultCredentials -Uri $url -Body $body -ContentType application/json-patch+json
     Write-Host "Change work item $workItemId" -ForegroundColor Green
  }
  catch
  {
     Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor Red
  }
```

Comment: Thanks!
but I get an error. to bypass the rules, you must be an administrator.
```
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF401322: для обхода правил необходимо быть администратором.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.WorkItemUnauthorizedRuleBypassException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server","typeKey":"WorkItemUnauthorizedRuleBypassException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3200}
```

Comment: If you don't have permissions to bypass rules so set it to false: `$byPass = "false"`. but if in the work item has incorrect fields value you can't save it and you can't change the assigned to.